# Identifying a coastal shark with a broad dorsal fin

Tags: animal-identification, sharks

Snagged this guy in the Port Royal Sound off the coast of Hilton Head Island, South Carolina last week. At first I thought it might be a bull shark but the dorsal profile doesn't really seem to match. The captain on the boat estimated it to be about 6 feet in length and weight 250 pounds. It broke off the leader just as we got it to side so I do not have any better pictures than this one.

To me the key characteristics are the large round dorsal fin, the broad round pectoral fins, light gray/sandy color.

Any thoughts on what species this may be?

[image: shark to be identified at surface of water]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the right color for a Oceanic white tip they have a barownish color to them and they are open water guys they stay way out there in the ocean and their fins are rounded with distinct white tips.

Reminds me of a sandbar shark... The Black tip is a reef shark and the white tip looks much different if I had to guess I would say sandbar shark.

[image]

This is a picture of a sandbar shark or you can look it up on google its for sure a sandbar shark

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with Blacktip shark (*Carcharhinus limbatus*). I see that there are no black tips on this one, but they can fade as adults.

Black tipped sharks have long fins with a more triangular shape to them than other sharks, they also have small second dorsal fins, and the first dorsal fin starts just over or behind the pectoral fins.

See [here](https://www.floridamuseum.ufl.edu/discover-fish/species-profiles/carcharhinus-limbatus/) for more information and descriptive pictures.

Comment: Thanks! I used that link to compare to some other species as well. What do you think about an Oceanic Whitetip (*Carcharhinus longimanus*)? Could their tips fade as well? I think the fin shape matches better than the Blacktip.

Comment: @Skooba could well be a whitetip, but I am definitely no shark expert. I am sure someone on here is though, so I would wait a while longer to see what responses you get.